# Get element from other web site into my div with out deleting content

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have an html page (comp.html) with div "content" with some float elements, and under my div I have a link. After pushing this link (a #addphoto) into my div, a div from another page (#photo_content from boxes.html) should be inserted. How can I do this?

html:

```
<div class="content clearfix">
     <div class="photo">1</div>
     <div class="photo">2</div>
     <div class="photo">3</div>
     <div class="photo">4</div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="addphoto"></a>
```

css for it:

```
.content{
     width: 600px;
}
.photo{
     float:left;
     width:150px;
}
```

please help brothers, I'm really bad in jquery and Ajax

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: It's not entirely clear what is supposed to happen, what you have tried and why that doesn't work.

Comment: I should insert div from second.html into div class="content clearfix" of first.html

Comment: what's inside second.html? have you tried anything with Ajax?

Comment: inside second html - boxes.html: section id="photo_content" there are many repeated classes like in first page class="photo"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://www.google.be",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $('.content').append(html);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something like this:

JQuery code:

```
function loadSecond()
{
    $.get('second.html', function(data) {
          $('.content clearfix').html(data);
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="content clearfix">
     <div class="photo">1</div>
     <div class="photo">2</div>
     <div class="photo">3</div>
     <div class="photo">4</div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="addphoto" onclick="loadSecond()">Load Second.html</a>
```